# Is there a more detailed version of top?

Tags: unix, top

I'm testing some software on a particular four core machine. Is there an option for `top` or a similar utility that can tell how much each core is being used for a particular job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 mpstat -P ALL
```

mpstat is part of the the sysstat package.

Output look like this -

```
07:44:18     CPU   %user   %nice %system %iowait    %irq   %soft   %idle    intr/s
07:44:18     all    3.01   57.31    0.36    0.13    0.01    0.00   39.19   1063.46
07:44:18       0    5.87   69.47    0.44    0.05    0.01    0.01   24.16    262.11
07:44:18       1    1.79   48.59    0.36    0.23    0.00    0.00   49.02    268.92
07:44:18       2    2.19   42.63    0.28    0.16    0.01    0.00   54.73    260.96
07:44:18       3    2.17   68.56    0.34    0.06    0.03    0.00   28.83    271.47
```

This page will be helpful for you - http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-linux-cpu-utilization.html

Answer (score 4):

[htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/). Configurable, detailed, and a little more user friendly than standard `top`.

Comment: Does it actually show per core usage?

Comment: @Daniel It has an option, under the "Columns" tab under "Setup", which is named "PROCESSOR". This will tell you which processor a process/thread is resident on, and the seperate "PERCENT_CPU" column will tell you how much CPU% it is using. So, yes. Kind of.